# Twitter Data Extraction of our followers Manually in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need To extract the tweets tweeted by ,whoever i am following ,for example,if am following Narendramodi,i want o extract his tweets from my home page using `beautifulsoap` and `requests` `module`.

```
username=myaccount
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
url='https://twitter.com/PMOIndia/status/1143820980604694528'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

x=soup.findAll('p',{'class':'TweetTextSize'})
for y in x:
    print(y.text)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is the code failing? Also, to extract data from Twitter, it is always advisable to use their APIs.

Comment: the problem is i am not getting follower tweets those whoever i am following

Comment: if i am following Modi or some x person ,whenever he tweets ,it will show in my twitter home page,but if i am trying to access their tweets i am not getting,i am getting my tweets,so this is the problem

Comment: suggest me the code please

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update will help you.

Comment: ya but it is using api,i dont need api,i need without api

Comment: I ran your code and it looks correct. One thing - you are overriding `url`, so remove the 2nd assignment. Otherwise, it is returning all tweets from profile page.

Comment: 2nd url i have put that in comment,from first url only i am getting my tweets,consider first url only,but its giving my tweets,but i need follower tweets

Comment: That's what I mentioned. I ran your code as-is with the first `url`, and it returned my tweets and those of users I'm following, basically all that is there in my user profile page. I inspected the tags in HTML source and what you used is correct. Maybe add couple of separator lines and it'll be easy to view the output.

Comment: i have tried in that way also but i am not getting,if u know that please share that code

Comment: Hi, my bad, sorry! I realized that the user's profile page does not show tweets of user being followed. It shows the retweets if the user has done one, and I was mixing that up as their tweet. In that case, it is not possible to get those tweets directly. You might have to go to "following" tab, find names, and check their profile pages individually. Or else, use APIs :)

Comment: I also think like that,that is only the possible way

Comment: Thanq so much for ur help